# Shortcut for adding to List in a HashMap

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I often have a need to take a list of objects and group them into a Map based on a value contained in the object. Eg. take a list of Users and group by Country.

My code for this usually looks like:

```
Map<String, List<User>> usersByCountry = new HashMap<String, List<User>>();
for(User user : listOfUsers) {
    if(usersByCountry.containsKey(user.getCountry())) {
        //Add to existing list
        usersByCountry.get(user.getCountry()).add(user);

    } else {
        //Create new list
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>(1);
        users.add(user);
        usersByCountry.put(user.getCountry(), users);
    }
}
```

However I can't help thinking that this is awkward and some guru has a better approach. The closest I can see so far is the [MultiMap from Google Collections](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).

Are there any standard approaches?

Thanks!

Comment: Should that really be `Map<String, Set<User>>`? The answer makes a difference for what you choose to build or use. Note that Google Collections provides refinements for the nested collections being of various types of lists and sets.

Comment: Just drop Java for .Net and Linq.

Comment: @Hamish: yeah, because of our worries about dependencies are totally irrelevant then!

Comment: @Hamish: I could never face my .Net coding brother again if I did that. The shame!

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Since Java 8 you can make use of [`Map#computeIfAbsent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)).

```
Map<String, List<User>> usersByCountry = new HashMap<>();

for (User user : listOfUsers) {
    usersByCountry.computeIfAbsent(user.getCountry(), k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(user);
}
```

Or, make use of Stream API's [`Collectors#groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function)) to go from `List` to `Map` directly:

```
Map<String, List<User>> usersByCountry = listOfUsers.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(User::getCountry));
```

In Java 7 or below, best what you can get is below:

```
Map<String, List<User>> usersByCountry = new HashMap<>();

for (User user : listOfUsers) {
    List<User> users = usersByCountry.get(user.getCountry());
    if (users == null) {
        users = new ArrayList<>();
        usersByCountry.put(user.getCountry(), users);
    }
    users.add(user);
}
```

[Commons Collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/) has a [`LazyMap`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-4.4/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/LazyMap.html), but it's not parameterized. [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) doesn't have sort of a `LazyMap` or `LazyList`, but you can use [`Multimap`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) for this as shown in [answer of polygenelubricants below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019376/shortcut-for-adding-to-list-in-a-hashmap/3021037#3021037).

Comment: You could shorten it a bit further: `usersByCountry.put(user.getCountry(), users = new ArrayList<>());` Though I'm sure some would frown on that.

Answer (score 23):

Guava's [`Multimap`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) really is the most appropriate data structure for this, and in fact, there is [`Multimaps.index(Iterable<V>, Function<? super V,K>)`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#index%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) utility method that does exactly what you want: take an [`Iterable<V>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) (which a [`List<V>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is), and apply the [`Function<? super V, K>`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r13/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html) to get the keys for the `Multimap<K,V>`.

Here's an example from the documentation:

> For example,
>
> ```
>   List<String> badGuys
>       = Arrays.asList("Inky", "Blinky", "Pinky", "Pinky", "Clyde");
>   Function<String, Integer> stringLengthFunction = ...;
>   Multimap<Integer, String> index
>       = Multimaps.index(badGuys, stringLengthFunction);
>   System.out.println(index);
> ```
>
> prints
>
> ```
>  {4=[Inky], 5=[Pinky, Pinky, Clyde], 6=[Blinky]}
> ```

In your case you'd write a `Function<User,String> userCountryFunction = ...`.

Comment: +1 It frustrates me that answers involving writing a lot more code than this are ranked higher, just because they were the fastest to come in. :(

Comment: @Kevin: I was hoping you'd stop by eventually =) By the way, I plan to eventually write Q/A articles on stackoverflow on various Guava classes to demonstrate its capabilities.

Comment: I stop by only once or twice a day, thus guaranteeing that I never have a chance to get my answers upvoted. <sigh>  I think your idea is a great one. I assume you mean posting a question and answering it yourself. You'll get a few people telling you there's something immoral about this, but it is explicitly sanctioned by the broader SO community, since their goal is for SO to have great content.

Answer (score 2):

When I have to deal with a collection-valued map, I just about always wind up writing a little putIntoListMap() static utility method in the class. If I find myself needing it in multiple classes, I throw that method into a utility class. Static method calls like that are a bit ugly, but they're much cleaner than typing the code out every time. Unless multi-maps play a pretty central role in your app, IMHO it's probably not worth it to pull in another dependency.

Answer (score 2):

By using [lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/) you can obtain that result with just one line of code as it follows:

```
Group<User> usersByCountry = group(listOfUsers, by(on(User.class).getCountry()));
```

Lambdaj also offers lots of other features to manipulate collections with a very readable domain specific language.

Answer (score 2):

We seem to do this a lot of times so I created a template class

```
public abstract class ListGroupBy<K, T> {
public Map<K, List<T>> map(List<T> list) {
    Map<K, List<T> > map = new HashMap<K, List<T> >();
    for (T t : list) {
        K key = groupBy(t);
        List<T> innerList = map.containsKey(key) ? map.get(key) : new ArrayList<T>();
        innerList.add(t);
        map.put(key, innerList);
    }
    return map;
}

protected abstract K groupBy(T t);
}
```

You just provide impl for groupBy

in your case

```
String groupBy(User u){return user.getCountry();}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Map<String, List<User>> usersByCountry = new HashMap<String, List<User>>();
for(User user : listOfUsers) {
    List<User> users = usersByCountry.get(user.getCountry());
    if (users == null) {        
        usersByCountry.put(user.getCountry(), users = new ArrayList<User>());
    }
    users.add(user);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your exact needs are met by [LinkedHashMultimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/LinkedHashMultimap.html) in the GC library.  If you can live with the dependencies, all your code becomes:

```
SetMultimap<String,User> countryToUserMap = LinkedHashMultimap.create();
// .. other stuff, then whenever you need it:
countryToUserMap.put(user.getCountry(), user);
```

insertion order is maintained (about all it looks like you were doing with your list) and duplicates are precluded; you can of course switch to a plain hash-based set or a tree set as needs dictate (or a list, though that doesn't seem to be what you need).  Empty collections are returned if you ask for a country with no users, everyone gets ponies, etc - what I mean is, check out the API.  It'll do a lot for you, so the dependency might be worth it.

Comment: +1 Thanks that's good to know but BalusC's optinmization was what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

A clean and readable way to add an element is the following:

```
String country = user.getCountry();
Set<User> users
if (users.containsKey(country))
{
    users = usersByCountry.get(user.getCountry());
}
else
{
    users = new HashSet<User>();
    usersByCountry.put(country, users);
}
users.add(user);
```

Note that calling `containsKey` and `get` is not slower than just calling `get` and testing the result for `null`.

Comment: The call at its own is indeed not slower, but the lookup now occurs twice instead of once.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList numbersList
= new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8));

Map<Integer, Long> elementCountMap = numbersList.stream()
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), v -> 1L, Long::sum));

System.out.println(elementCountMap);

o/p:{1=2, 2=1, 3=3, 4=1, 5=1, 6=3, 7=1, 8=1}