# If I have a HashMap where the values are a list, can I stream a certain index of that list into a new list?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am looking to take a Hashmap that has many key/value pairs where each value has a list.  I want to take an index, and make a list based on that index.

Essentially I am looking to take this code and turn it into a stream.

```
HashMap < Integer , List< Object >> map = new HashMap();
                     //name //age 
map.put("1", new List("Bob",20));
map.put("2", new List("Jim",37));
map.put("3", new List("Dan",30));
map.put("3", new List("Rick",40));

  List < Integer > s = new ArrayList();

  map.values().forEach(e - >
  {
      s.add(( Integer ) e.get(1)); //looking to extract all of the ages into
  });                            // a new list.
```

In my use case, each index of the list is a different type of object, so in this case I tried to use a String and an Integer.  I mention this in case there is a way to select an item based on an object's type to put into the new list.  I had found this example that mentioned "groupingBy" as a `Collector`'s option, but It doesn't seem to work for my use-case

[Shortcut for adding to List in a HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019376/shortcut-for-adding-to-list-in-a-hashmap)

Thank you for any help

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I was in the process of editing the question myself which is why your edit didn't go through, is that why I was downvoted?

Comment: I don't know why your question was down-voted, but it may be closed for being unclear. Consider posting more explanation and better, real-world code that demonstrates the problem better.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I rolled back your edit and applied my edits to them, I hope that works for you.  I will try to add more to this example to make it more clear.

Comment: You know that this: `map.add("3", new List("Dan","30");
map.add("3", new List("Rick","40");` will only hold the last addition in the map, and then the preceding line of data, Dan/30, will be discarded. Also your code has a bad anti-pattern, using an array or List as a substitute for a class. Much better to have the value data be a custom class that holds a name String and an age int (or date of birth). This will make creating your stream *much* easier and much more intuitive.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  Thank you.  I realized I had a few mistakes I had to edit, and that add should be "put."   It does make sense that a class would be better, I had figured with only a few pieces of data in that array it wouldn't warrant a class, but I can see why it would be better.  I think that collectors "GroupingBy" also might work out better with that.  I'll try it out adn report back... Thank you very much for all of your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a stream of the map's `values` collection, use `Stream.map` to extract the values you care about, and then `Stream.collect` to make a new collection.

```java
List<Integer> ages = map.values().stream()
    .map(list -> (Integer) list.get(1))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I agree with the commenter on the question who said you should really make these into actual POJO objects - the code will be a lot clearer and less error prone if you do. If you go that route then you can use a method reference to get the ages:

```
.map(Person::getAge)
```

Comment: This seems to work great, thank you very much.  I will have to look into the map function in depth.