# Is there a one-liner for list creation and element addition?

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, arraylist, one-liner

Say we have to iterate over a list of complex object, and "group" them in a map where a key is (for example) a date and the relative value is a list of complex objects that share that same date.

I'm a sucker for elegant and readable code, in my way though.

1. I love one liners after loops and conditional constructs as they do not require "{" & "}";
2. I hate declaring variables I will not re-use;

```
Map<ZonedDateTime, List<ComplexObject >> map = new HashMap<>();
        
for(var complexObject : complexObjectsList)
            
    if (map.containsKey(complexObject.getZonedDateTime()))

        map.get(complexObject.getZonedDateTime()).add(complexObject);

    else

        map.put(complexObject.getZonedDateTime(), new ArrayList<ComplexObject>().add(complexObject));
```

As you can see, for and if/else constructs do not need {} nor additional lines.

The problem here, is:

in the case of a date not present yet in the map, I would love to add it in a one-liner, also creating the list with the first element inside. However, since ArrayList's ".add" method does not return a List (which is what the map value expects) and, instead, returns a boolean, I cannot do so.

I'm forced to declare a new List a few lines higher, add the element in another line, and then pass it. Consequentially, I will have to use "{}", multiple lines and a variable declaration that is not going to be used anymore.

Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3019388/5133585) solve your problem? If you are asking about something more general, please [edit] to show a more general situation of where you would need this.

Comment: I'm not a java developer and I know this is probably out of context BUT: Why would you prefer a "one liner" that is probably less readable instead of multiple lines that make sense the moment you look at them...

Comment: Should "`measure`" be `complexObject`?

Comment: @MarkusSafar mostly personal. Too much boilerplate code to just create a list, add an element, and add the list to the map. In this small scope it makes sense, but in a way bigger structure (such as the one I'm working on) it's really pointless code. Maybe it's subjective.

Comment: @Sweeper no I don't think so. What I need is a one-liner to create a list and add an element to it without instantiating it first. It would help to keep the structure of the logic as is for readability, while adopting that solution would totally delete the structure for one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However the question is about having a one line where you can create a list, add an element to it, and return the list.

Depends on the kind of list you want:

- An unmodifiable, null-hostile list: `List.of(element)`.
- A modifiable, non-resizable, null-tolerant list: `Arrays.asList(element)`.
- A modifiable, resizable list: `new ArrayList<>(/* one of the above suggestions */)`, e.g. `new ArrayList<>(List.of(element))`.

Many other ways also exist, e.g. `Stream.of(element).collect(toList())`, many other list implementations exist, e.g. `ImmutableList.of(element)` with Guava.

---

Another way of approaching the problem outlined in the question, which is basically creating a new list and adding an element to it would be:

```
map.computeIfAbsent(complexObject.getZonedDateTime(), k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(complexObject);
```

---

I challenge your preference towards omitting `{}` and doing things in one-liners: neither of these are good general approaches:

- `{}` are useful visual cues, which help people reading the code to identify the start and end of blocks. They also guard against some kinds of mistakes when the code is modified in the future, for example intending to add something in the block, but not in fact doing so, because the braces are omitted.

  Note that some style guides, e.g. [Google's Java style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.1-braces) require the use of optional braces, to improve readability of the code.
- One-liners can, in certain circumstances, be the best way to write things; in many circumstances they can make things much harder to express.

  I would probably choose `List.of(element)` or `Array.asList(element)` if I needed an unmodifiable list - that's nice and easy, clear. But once you start using `new ArrayList<>(List.of(element))`, that starts getting quite a bit harder to read, because there's a lot of burden imposed by the API - why the diamond brackets, why create a list and then create another list? You can hide some of this burden by extracting a method; but then, isn't a method more verbose than a variable?

  So, you have to declare a variable if you write something as a not-one-liner. Does that matter? It doesn't make the code slower; it may make it easier to read, because you're given the opportunity to provide type information (unless you've used `var`) and a name to indicate the purpose.

Ultimately, you should optimize for *readable* code. Far more time is (or should be) spent reading code than writing code. The poor person who has to read your code next might be you - it's easy to forget what you meant when you return to the code a week, a month, a year later.

Be kind, take the time to help future you.

Comment: `Arrays.asList(element)` actually produces mutable, but non-resizable list.

Comment: I disagree a little, even though I know the status quo follows these directions.
You don't need visual clues such as {} to understand where a piece of code starts and where it finishes as one line structures are only one line and can be read like spoken english. Look:

For each element of the List, if the Map contains it, deepen it
else, add it

And if you have to add boilerplate code such as instantiating a list, add an element to it and then add the list to the new element of the map, you disrupt the reading. It's definitely personal opinion though.

Comment: @SalvatoreGrazioso of course, you're entitled to disagree. But, please recognize the data point that Google (and perhaps other companies) considers it not just a practice worth recommending, but a practice that is worth _enforcing_ within their codebase.

Comment: @SalvatoreGrazioso Those visual clues become vital when poring over code in a crashing app at 3 AM.

Comment: @BasilBourque what do you need the visual clues for? It's exactly 1 line you don't need to know where it finishes. You can't omit {} with multiple rows.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jdk8 or higher, you can use stream to achieve it:

```
Map<ZonedDateTime, List<ComplexObject >> map = complexObjectsList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ComplexObject::getZonedDateTime))
```

Comment: I had no idea this existed and this reduces drastically the amount of lines. However the question is about having a one line where you can create a list, add an element to it, and return the list. Thanks though!

Comment: It is perhaps worth adding that the reason this should be preferred over OP's `containsKey/put` approach is that this avoids repeated lookups into the map.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple solutions to this problem, you could use `HashMap::compute` or [`Collectors::groupingBy`](https://ideone.com/oYfntC)

```
class Ideone
{
    class ComplexObject
    {
        ZonedDateTime time;
        ZonedDateTime getDateTime() { return time; }
    }
    
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        List<ComplexObject> objects = new ArrayList<>();
        
        Map<ZonedDateTime, List<ComplexObject>> map = objects.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ComplexObject::getDateTime));
    }
}
```

Comment: I had no idea this existed and this reduces drastically the amount of lines. However the question is about having a one line where you can create a list, add an element to it, and return the list. Thanks though!

Comment: You mean something like `new ArrayList<>(List.of(element))`?

Comment: yes! Exactly. I can't upvote yet unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) and achieve what you want and also get rid of the if-else block

```
Map<ZonedDateTime, List<ComplexObject >> map = new HashMap<>();
    
for(var complexObject : complexObjectsList)
    map.computeIfAbsent(complexObject.getZonedDateTime(), k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(complexObject);
```